# jquery dynamically added div tags and adding elements in them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code which adds a new line with a link I want be clickable. It creates two div tags and I would like to add html in the `.we` div. I have tried different combinations but nothing seems to work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test"></div>
    <input type="button" id="add" value="Add New Line" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            $("#add").click(function () {
                var id = new Date().getTime();
                var common_fields = "<div style='background-color:#f0f0f0' class='move_line'><div id='we'></div><input type='hidden' value=''>" + 
                    "<a href='#' class='new_user'>Add User</a><br /><br />Common field 1: <input type='text' id='" + id + "'/>&nbsp;<hr></div>";
                $("#test").append(common_fields);
            });

            $("body").on("click", ".new_user", function () {
                $(this).closest("div.move_line").closest("div.we").append("<span>prosper</span>");
            });

        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create divs with the ID of we (`<div id='we'>`), but then look for the div with the CLASS we (`"div.we"`). Note that IDs must be unique anyway, and that .`closest()` searches up the DOM whereas you want `.find()` which searches descendants.

This corrects those errors:

```
 $("#add").click(function () {
     var id = new Date().getTime();
     var common_fields = "<div style='background-color:#f0f0f0' class='move_line'><div class='we'></div><input type='hidden' value=''>" +
         "<a href='#' class='new_user'>Add User</a><br /><br />Common field 1: <input type='text' id='" + id + "'/>&nbsp;<hr></div>";
     $("#test").append(common_fields);
 });
 $("body").on("click", ".new_user", function () {
     $(this).closest("div.move_line").find("div.we").append("<span>prosper</span>");
 });
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Low88fg9/)**